# Follow up question about pulling SO questions to DA: How do you pull questions to DA?

Tags: support, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to pull Drupal questions from StackOverflow to Drupal Answers?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-it-possible-to-pull-drupal-questions-from-stackoverflow-to-drupal-answers)

Was reading this question: [Is it possible to pull Drupal questions from StackOverflow to Drupal Answers?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-it-possible-to-pull-drupal-questions-from-stackoverflow-to-drupal-answers)

Now this is from a year ago.

Is this currently possible since DA.SE is now out of beta?

If so how do you go about doing this?

Comment: The accepted answer for that question already answers you; my answer explains how it is possible to ask for the migration of questions from Stack Overflow. Actually, Stack Overflow moderators cooperate in migrating questions to Drupal Answers.