# What other questions should be added to our FAQ?

Tags: discussion

On this very meta there are some questions tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), which are a guidelines about how to use *Drupal Answers*, and which questions are off-topic/on-topic.

I am planning to add more FAQ questions which would be used as guideline for all those users who don't visit Meta Stack Overflow, and who don't know how things work on Stack Exchange sites. Clearly, the questions reported in this FAQ are just a small part of what the Meta Stack Overflow FAQ reports, and should be a guide for the main issues seen on *Drupal Answers*.

The questions I was thinking of are the following ones:

- When should I flag a post for moderation attention?
- When should I flag an answer as "not an answer"? (A.k.a. I flagged a post as "not an answer," but the flag has been declined because it should not be used for a wrong answer. What does that mean?)
- When should I flag a post as "very low quality"?
- My flag for closing a question has been declined, but the question is now closed. What happened?
- I have offered a bounty for my question that has not assigned to any answer. Why?
- If a moderator comments on a post, does that mean the moderator is going to do anything about the post, and the community doesn't need to do anything?
- In which way can I help moderating *Drupal Answers*?
- Why should I accept an answer for the questions I ask?
- How do @-references work?
- Are tags allowed in question's titles?
- Are tags automatically removed? (The answer is provided by [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/140449).)
- How can I force the correct highlighting for the code I use in my posts?
- [Is it possible to pull Drupal questions from StackOverflow to Drupal Answers?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-it-possible-to-pull-drupal-questions-from-stackoverflow-to-drupal-answers)
- How do I appropriately use the tags? (This would be similar to [this question](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455/what-is-the-purpose-of-tags-how-do-i-use-them-appropriately) on another meta site.)
- When is it appropriate to flag a question to close it?
- What should I do when I put sensitive information in a post, and I need to remove them? (The answer is given in [this chat post](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3926653#3926653).)
- Why are some questions tagged "untagged"? What can I do when I find such questions?

Can you think of more questions that could be added to our FAQ? Are there any question already asked on this meta site that could be generalized, and made part of our FAQ?

Answer (score 7):

When is it appropriate to edit a question/answer?

Answer (score 5):

Should I report bugs in Drupal or modules on drupal.org here?

Can I crosspost my question to drupal.org?

Answer (score 2):

## [Why Vote? / Voting](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/why-does-nobody-vote-around-here-and-why-they-need-to)

Higher on the page than "What is reputation?", (which could itself be revisited).

This community in particular seems to need more voters and I think it's far more important a topic than whether one has to log in or not to post questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd be good to see something along the lines of *"When is it appropriate to use version tags"*  as this seems to be a bit of a grey area.

Comment: +1 agreed, maybe the text should also link through to the fabled [Version tags considered harmful](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229/version-tags-considered-harmful) and [Numeric version tags considered ... OK](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251/numeric-version-tags-considered-ok) posts ;)

Comment: It is not possible to give a definitive answer to this question. I think it is fine to add [tag:6] to a question asking about a module to use, but I would rather not see three different questions asking about the same type of module, tagged with 3 different Drupal version tags.

Comment: Perhaps the version tags should be considered OK as per @kiamlaluno's comment, but put somewhere that if an answer covers multiple versions then it may be untagged?  For example:  Say there is a Views question for 6, but the answer covers the 7.x version as well, then it should be untagged?

Or something along those lines...